# Apex wrapper variable with null values are not returning in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class, imperativeapex

I have an apex method which is returning Wrapper List.Some of the Wrapper Variables has values as null.Those null values and there variable names are not returning in LWC.

Wrapper Data:

```
[AccountNo  = 1012273872837,
ActualShipDate  = null,
AttName         = test,
AttNumber       = null,
City            = BANGALORE,
Country         = India,
EstimatedDate   = null]
```

I want to access **ActualShipDate,AttNumber,EstimatedDate** variables but unable to see them in my LWC even though in the Apex logs I can see the data is present.

I tried replacing the null values with empty strings but **EstimatedDate** is date type variable and it is throwing error from apex side.

Can anyone suggest any approach for?

Comment: Adding your apex controller code can help us give you a better answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this question right, then when you are calling your method in LWC js using wire then in result you will be having all data and if you want to assign it to some particular value in LWC then you can perform this action

```
@wire(method)
methodParam(result){
this.data = result.map( wrapper => {
this.shipDate = wrapper.ActualShipDate
});
```

that's how you can approach. Here, ActualShipDate is wrapper variable which you must be getting from your apex and shipDate is the variable defined in LWC.
I Hope it helps. If not, more controller code would be helpful.